# How to replace just last character?

Tags: mysql, replace

Here is my table:

```
// table
+----+--------+
| id | number |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 123    |
| 2  | 123.   |
| 3  | 12.3   |
+----+--------+
```

I want this:

```
// newtable
+----+--------+
| id | number |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 123    |
| 2  | 123    |
| 3  | 12.3   |
+----+--------+
```

How can I do that?

I can do that like this: *(But I'm searching for faster and better approach)*

```
// Not tested, But I think this works!
SELECT 
  id, 
  IF(RIGHT(number,1) == '.', REPLACE(number, '.', ''), number)
FROM table
// also I can use CAST(number as unsigned) instead of REPLACE(number, '.', '')
```

Well, is there any better solution? (without `IF`-statement)

Comment: Are you saying that a column called `number` is not stored using a numeric type?  That seems like the first problem.

Comment: At first: What do you want to achieve? Do you perhaps want to replace the values ending with a dot character in the database? Do you just want to change the output of the database?

Comment: @GordonLinoff `number` has `int(11)` type. But I used something like this in my query `ROUND(number/1000,1)` and then `.` *(point)* will appear... Also I used `SUBSTR()` and then sometimes I get a `.` in the end of that number, Now I want to remove it.

Comment: @HerrSerker What I'm trying to do is detecting a better approach for doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825323/how-to-show-big-numbers-per-k-stands-for-kilo/33826706#33826706). Actually I want to eliminate that middle `IF`-statement.

Comment: Perhaps ypu should adress this in the output and not in the business logic? What language/framework do you query from?

Comment: @HerrSerker Honestly I didn't get your question, I used phpmyadmin for using of database and PHP for dynamic codes.

Comment: @Shafizadeh Well, you certainly want to do something with the output from the database. But what you try to achieve is changing the output format of the database output. Maybe a database query is not the best place to do this. Format should be handled in the output itself (for example PHP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove last corresponding characters if exist

```
SELECT id, TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM number) FROM test
```

Comment: It's always a good thing to add an explanation for your code. Also, although it's not forbidden, it would be better if you provide the possible solutons in the same answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id, CONVERT(number, DECIMAL(10,6)) FROM test
```

Comment: Can you please add some explain to your answer? What is `DECIMAL(10,6)` ?

Comment: `DECIMAL(10,6)` mean the number have 10 digits 4 of them before the fixed point and 6 after it

Comment: the output will be always like this 'X.yyyyyy' X can be 0 or higher but yyyyyy are always 6 , ex. '100.000000' for integer 100 or '0.666667' for 2/3

Answer (score 2):

use this if you want to change the data in the table

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test(
    -> id INT(1),
    -> number VARCHAR(5)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test
    -> VALUES(1, '123'),
    -> (2, '123.'),
    -> (3, '12.3');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+------+--------+
| id   | number |
+------+--------+
|    1 | 123    |
|    2 | 123.   |
|    3 | 12.3   |
+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE test
    -> SET number=REPLACE(number, '.', '')
    -> WHERE RIGHT(number,1) = '.';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+------+--------+
| id   | number |
+------+--------+
|    1 | 123    |
|    2 | 123    |
|    3 | 12.3   |
+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and use this if you want just to get the data in this form

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE test(
    ->   id INT(1),
    ->   number VARCHAR(5)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test VALUES
    ->   (1, '123'),
    ->   (2, '123.'),
    ->   (3, '12.3')
    -> ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+------+--------+
| id   | number |
+------+--------+
|    1 | 123    |
|    2 | 123.   |
|    3 | 12.3   |
+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   id,
    ->   CASE
    ->     WHEN RIGHT(number,1) = '.' THEN floor(number)
    ->     ELSE number
    ->   END AS number
    -> from test;
+------+--------+
| id   | number |
+------+--------+
|    1 | 123    |
|    2 | 123    |
|    3 | 12.3   |
+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Your solution is fine. But actually it is not what I wanted. +1

Comment: you don't want to change it in the database ?

Comment: okay sorry i got it wrong first time , gonna try something else

Comment: i edit the answer , i don't think it's what you need too